# Damage redirection in Warhammer Invasion

Tags: warhammer-invasion

Some cards like Warrior Priest from Empire deck has a damage redirection rule. How exactly does this rule work?

For example: if my opponent assigns 1 damage to my Warrior Priest can I simply move the damage token to any unit surviving the battle and ignore the damage on the Priest or is it an extra damage that Priest will deal but will die anyway because he was assigned enough damage to kill him?

[image: Warrior Priests]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order should proceed like this:

1. All damage is assigned (leave the damage tokens near the unit to be damaged)  Note: a target may be over assigned damage at the player's discretion but this is not required except in the case of damage cancellation even when you know the unit will survive due to other protective effects
2. Certain effects trigger and are resolved including redirecting damage.  In this case, the Priests are able to redirect one damage point, preferably to a unit with toughness
3. Damage is moved onto the card, destroying any cards that still have damage equal to its hit points.

Source - FAQ and Rules on [Fantasy Flight's](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=85&esem=4) website

Comment: Can the damage be redirected to opponent's unit?

Comment: Yes, you can redirect to your opponent's units (as evidenced by the card saying "any battlefield" instead of "your battlefield").